# Email configuration in CakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp, timeout

I'm trying to send mails through CakePHP, but I always got a 'Connection timed out' message. I've used two different configurations: gmail and 1and1, but result is the same.

This is my `email.php` file:

```
 public $oneandone = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.1and1.es',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my-address@my-domain.com',
    'password' => '*****',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'timeout' => 1);

public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => 'my-address@gmail.com',
    'password' => '****',
    'timeout' => 1,
    'tls' => true,
    'transport' => 'Smtp');
```

And this is my remind function inside the `UsersController.php` file:

```
 public function remind() {

    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

    $this->set('url', $this->referer());

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
        $Email->from(array('my-address@my-domain.com' => 'Staff'));
        $Email->to('destiny@hotmail.com');
        $Email->subject('Password reminder');
        $Email->send('Here is your current password: xxxxxx');

        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
    }
}
```

The error I got is

```
 if (!$this->_socket->connect()) {

        throw new SocketException(__d('cake_dev', 'Unable to connect to SMTP server.'));
```

so I don't know why I'm not being able to connect. I've modified some params like `tls`, `ssl` but no results.

Within the same server (1and1) I can send emails with the standard `mail()` function, so I don't think it is a problem of PHP configuration. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Some ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the following, worked me correctly.  on Cakephp 2

```
public $gmail = array(
'host'      => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
'port'      => 465,
'username'  => 'myEmail@gmail.com',
'password'  => 'AwesomePass',
'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

Note that gmail uses port 465.
It is possible that gmail does not work if your site does not have ssl certification.

in this case you must use a smtp configuration

```
public $smtp = array(
'transport' => 'Smtp',
'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'My Site'),
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => 25,
'timeout' => 30,
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'secret',
'client' => null,
'log' => false,
//'charset' => 'utf-8',
//'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

with the following function

```
public function sendMail() {
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $templateVar = array(); //array variable to use in the template
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->template('template_name', 'default') //View/Emails/html/template_name.ctp
      ->config('gmail')//gmail or smtp
      ->emailFormat('html')
      ->subject('Awesome subject')
      ->to('toUser@email.com')
      ->from(array('myEmail@gmail.com'=>'My name'))
      ->viewVars($templateVar)
      ->send();
}
```